# Autohotkey: Replace Text Selection via Associative Array

Tags: autohotkey

I want to implement the following behavior with Autohotkey: 
After Control+Shift+P is pressed, the currently selected text should be replaced by the value that is stored in a dictionary.

I tried the following:

```
^+P::
    Send, ^x ;cut current text selection
    dict := { "key1" : "value", "key2" : "value 2" } ; associative array
    Clipboard=%dict%.%Clipboard%
    Send, ^v ;paste back treated text
```

Which however only prints out the current clipboard contents preceded by a dot. It seems that the associative array isn't even created. What am I missing? And how can I check if a key is contained inside a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

**This replaces the currently selected text with a value stored in a dictionary**

```
dict := { "key1" : "value", "key2" : "value 2" }

^+P::
    Send, ^x
    ClipWait 1
    send % dict.HasKey(clipboard) ? dict[clipboard] : "???"
```